# How to pass the percentage of the progress in code behind to Jquery progress bar?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar

I have a background worker in asp.net. I would like to pass the percentage counted in progress changed and display it in jquery progress bar. Unfortunately,i found out it only update the progress bar once and only the progress is completed.

### Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar();
              setTimeout(updateProgress, 100);
    });

   function updateProgress() {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Downloader.aspx/GetData",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: true,
                  success: function(msg) {
                      // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

                      $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", msg.d);
                  }
              });
          }
```

### Downloader.aspx.cs

```
static BackgroundWorker _bw;
public static int Percent { get; set; }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bw = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        _bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

        _bw.RunWorkerAsync("Hello world");
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 20)
        {
            if (_bw.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
            _bw.ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        e.Result = 123;
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                       RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            percentage.Text = "Complete: " + e.Result;      // from DoWork
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender,
                                    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Percent = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static int GetData()
    {
        return Percent;
    }
```

**How to update the jquery progress bar once the bw_ProgressChanged detect any changes?**

Comment: is the problem exist because of postback problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recurse your `setTimeout()` in your ajax success function until the process completes.

This method is called ajax-polling.

**Mocked HTML:**

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    Percentage:<asp:Label ID="percentage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Client-side script:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // TODO: revert the line below in your actual code
        //$("#progressbar").progressbar();
        setTimeout(updateProgress, 100);
    });

    function updateProgress() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                // TODO: revert the line below in your actual code
                //$("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", msg.d);
                $("#percentage").text(msg.d);
                if (msg.d < 100) {
                    setTimeout(updateProgress, 100);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Code Behind:** *No change.*

Comment: This is not working, the progress bar only updated once the backgroundworker is completed.

Comment: @DEN, Was there any error? What is the value of `msg.d`? Can you try to remove `parseInt`? Also check if your `Percent` is indeed incrementing in the server-side.

Comment: there are no error. There are no different whether to remove the parseInt or not. The value of msg.d at first is 0, when the progress complete, the value is 100. It fail to get the progress value during from 0 to 100 :( will it be postback issue? or the value unable to get until the progress is finish loaded? Is that possible to get the progress changed value while the progress is running?

Comment: Ok, there was an extra `)` in my original post, so I removed that. I also tried this is my machine and it worked fine. (I don't know what `progressbar()` plugin you are using so in my test I just used a label to display the progress.) I also presume you have `Async="true"` set in your aspx page. **Please check edited answer.**

Comment: Alex, the result is same. it only update the progress bar when the progress is run completed but not updated in every 100 ms

Comment: @DEN, It could be a different issue from what you are saying. Because, as in my answer, I have tried the same solution I am proposing to you and it worked. The only difference is, I am not using whatever `progressbar` plugin you are using. Can you try with just a label and not that progressbar, as in my example?

Comment: Hi alex, i found the answer. The solution is ,i have to insert the Button1 control within the update panel in aspx. Anyway, i will mark yours as answer :) Thanks for the help!!

Comment: That's interesting :) So you still did the ajax-polling part, didn't you?

Comment: yea! it won't be working without ajax-polling. In your own testing on this question,u din't use any update panel?

Comment: Nope, what I put there was what worked for me. I didn't know you were working with an update panel.

Comment: I din't use it at first, but i found out this work for me only when i insert update panel

Answer (score 0):

you should use setInterval(yourfunctionname,1000) insted of setTimeout in document.ready .

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar();
              setInterval(updateProgress, 100);
    });
```